# Transform using range-v3

Tags: c++, c++17, c++20, range-v3

I am trying below code using ranges but it doesn't working.

```
// Code
std::map<int, std::string> m{ {1,"foo"},{42,"bar"},{7,"baz"} };
std::vector<int> keys;

// without using ranges
std::transform(begin(m), end(m), std::back_inserter(keys), [](auto val)
{
    return val.first;
});
```

which is working fine. But,

```
// with using ranges
ranges::transform(m,std::back_inserter(keys), [](auto val)
{
    return val.first;
});
```

it is not working with ranges??

I am using MSVC 2017 15.9.14

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The range-v3 doesn't support `std::back_insert_iterator`, because it doesn't satisfy the library `Iterator` concept, see [this issue](https://github.com/ericniebler/range-v3/issues/867). As it's pointed out in the discussion, this is supposed to be fixed with C++20.

You can fix this by either

```
keys.resize(3);

ranges::transform(m, keys.begin(), [](auto val) { return val.first; });
```

or, in my opinion preferable (as you can make `keys` `const`):

```
const std::vector<int> keys = m |
    ranges::view::transform([](auto val){ return val.first; });
```

As a side note, consider passing the lambda parameter as a `const`-qualified reference to avoid unnecessary copies.

Comment: Can go even shorter: `m | view::keys`

Comment: Thanks for answer @lubgr :- It helped me a lot.

Comment: I can also write like const auto keys = m | ranges::view::transform([](auto val){ return val.first; });

Comment: The implicit conversion of views to containers is deprecated. You should also pipe it through `ranges::to_vector`.

Comment: @sv90 Oh interesting, why has it been deprecated?

Comment: @lubgr This is the [commit](https://github.com/ericniebler/range-v3/commit/a0ab979f0b6b79e1994c6bbf8aa5c84baedbcff4) which deprecates it. There is no explanation.